# Query to get values for particular key in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, collections, nosql, mongodb-query, mongoid

I have a collection which contains records in the following format.

```
{
"_id" : 21,
"title" : "3D User Interfaces with Java 3D",
"isbn" : "1884777902",
"pageCount" : 520,
"publishedDate" : ISODate("2000-08-01T07:00:00Z"),
"thumbnailUrl" : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/AKIAJC5RLADLUMVRPFDQ.book-thumb-images/barrilleaux.jpg",
"longDescription" : "3D User Interfaces with Java 3D is a practical guide for providing next-generation applications with 3D user interfaces for manipulation of in-scene objects. Emphasis is on standalone and web-based business applications, such as for online sales and mass customization, but much of what this book offers has broad applicability to 3D user interfaces in other pursuits such as scientific visualization and gaming.  This book provides an extensive conceptual framework for 3D user interface techniques, and an in-depth introduction to user interface support in the Java 3D API, including such topics as picking, collision, and drag-and-drop. Many of the techniques are demonstrated in a Java 3D software framework included with the book, which also provides developers with many general-purpose building blocks for constructing their own user interfaces.    Applications and their use of 3D are approached realistically. The book is geared towards sophisticated user interfaces for the \"everyday user\" who doesn't have a lot of time to learn another application--much less a complicated one--and an everyday computer system without exotic devices like head mounted displays and data gloves. Perhaps the best description of this book is: \"A roadmap from Java 3D to 'Swing 3D'.\"",
"status" : "PUBLISH",
"authors" : [
    "Jon Barrilleaux"
],
"categories" : [
    "Java",
    "Computer Graphics"
]
```

}

What I want to do is extracting all the title values from the collection.

I tried to use something like:

```
db.<Collection_name>.find(title)
```

But it returns an error as **ReferenceError: title is not defined.**

Could you please provide your suggestions to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) methods takes two arguments: first one is for query (you can pass an empty object) and second one defines a projection (which fields should be returned) so your query should be like:

```
db.<Collection_name>.find({}, { title: 1 })
```